# To Master Flash Builder or not

Tags: flash

Good day stackoverflow..
I'll be creating a management system soon and I was wondering if i should pursue Mastering Flash Builder and ActionScript 3.0. Is Flash Builder good for these kinds of systems?
Can anyone help me with this? I seriously need your opinions. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience with Adobe Flex and GWT in enterprise apps.

I recomend GWT because Flash Builder sucks (google for it - then You'll know why).

But yes. Flex + ActionScrtipt3 will do the job - You'll just repeat WTF (much) more often :)